# how to access Android library kotlin functions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library

I wrote a simple function in my Android library which I want to use in my Android project. I am unable to access that library function from the android project.

Import is fine, I can get to Util class from the project. Just that I cannot get access to the kotlin function

Note: The Android library is within Android project

I get `Unresolved reference: specialToast`

Android library function

```
class Util {

    fun specialToast(context: Context, string: String) {
        Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Android project

```
import com.i6systems.offlineservicelibrary.Util

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Util.specialToast(applicationContext, "test")
        //****Unresolved reference: specialToast*****
    }
}
```

Thanks for your suggestion

R

Comment: If you are using 4.1 Canary, that may be this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155523324

Comment: I am using Android studio 3.6.2

Comment: To call instance method you need create instance first: `Util().specialToast(applicationContext, "test")` or replace `class` with `object` keyword

Comment: I created a companion object and placed the function in it and that worked. but what is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created a companion object and placed the function in it and that worked. but what is the right way?

The idiomatic Kotlin way is

> [The recommended practice is to never use object for creating namespaces, and to always use top-level declarations when possible. We haven’t found name conflicts to be an issue, and if you do get a conflict, you can resolve it using an import with alias.](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practices-for-top-level-declarations/2198)

So

```
// outside any class or object
fun specialToast(context: Context, string: String) {
    Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

in one file and

```
import com.i6systems.offlineservicelibrary.specialToast

...
specialToast(applicationContext, "test")
```

in the other.

Comment: it will be helpful if you could mention when to use companion object within a class and the approach you mentioned

Comment: When a function is tied to a specific class/interface but wouldn't make sense as a member. But even that's not a strict rule, e.g. `arrayOf` could probably be declared in an `Array` companion object and be `Array.of`, but isn't.